# EMV Tag 5F25 Application Effective Date == 49.12.31

Tags: android-pay, google-pay, emv

Google pay virtual Mastercard cards return 491231 in EMV Tag 5F25 (Application Effective Date)
which stands for 2049.12.31 according to 'M/Chip Requirements' document:

> Date from which the application may be used. The date is expressed
> in the YYMMDD format.
> For Mastercard branded applications if the value of YY ranges from ‘00’ to ‘49’ the date reads 20YYMMDD,
> if the value of YY ranges from ‘50’ to ‘99’, the date reads 19YYMMDD.

What does it mean and what should I do with this garbage? Set 'Application Not Yet Effective' bit in TVR as EMV books require, really? Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you should just set the bit in TVR.
This is the way non-expiring online-only cards are made (with no ODA capability).

Comment: Is there some document where I can read more about that?